# Вызовы MPI из разных потоков

Tags: hpc, многопоточность, c++, mpi

Проблема следующая: я вызываю несколько парных запросов с рута к слейвам по следующй схеме:

```
MPI_isend -> MPI_irecv -> slave work -> MPI_wait_all
```

На этапе **`MPI_isend`**, рут отсылает запрос еще и себе, но на этапе **`MPI_wait_all`** рут висит на ожидании обработки этого самого запроса, если **`slave work`** производится из другого потока.

Кто-нибудь может ответить, это нормальная ситуация, если уровень синхронизации выставлен в **`MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`**?

Answer (score 1):

В стандарте это не оговорено явно, поэтому зависит от реализации. Советую не делать отсылок самому себе, даже асинхронных, т.к. это потенциальный клинч.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше мнение?

Comment: В общем-то, [оговорено](http://parallel.ru/docs/mpi2/node165.html#Node165). Думаю, `MPI_wait_all` начинает работать раньше логики из потока, поэтому он блокирует любые вызовы MPI, в том числе и параллельные. На момент возникновения проблемы, я перепробовал все варианты синхронизации, кроме `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`, поддержки которого не было в реализации `MS-MPI`. Возможно, именно в этом режиме такая стратегия была бы работоспособной.

Comment: Был невнимателен, да в MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED это логичное поведение, так как если MPI_wait_all вызван раньше, чем MPI_irecv в другом потоке, то у второго потока уже нет шансов вызвать MPI_irecv.
В данном случае лучше использовать MPI_iprobe, например с указанием ANY_SOURCE, что конечно более хлопотно, но и более надёжно, так как нет блокирующих вызовов.